# i need to use the " symbol in java

Tags: java

I'm having some hard trouble finding the answer for this

Is there anyway to use the " symbol in java without it assumes that is a text... The ideal i think would be to save the " to a string.

Can it be done?

I need it because of this, the call of the script is working in dreamweaver

```
onChange="album(this.value,'albumAlvo')"
```

but I'm using a javascript call in a dynamic webpage generated by java, and for printing the page am changing the " to ' ending with this as example:

```
"<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='0' class='t1'>"+
    "<tr><td>"+
```

that changes my call to

```
    onChange='album(this.value,'albumAlvo')'>
```

And this way doesnt work. Apparently i really need the " to make this work. anyone can help me please?

Edited: Just a clearing, this question is about java and coding in a java environment in a java *.class, in a project for google app engine that uses java that prints html web-pages. The only reason why javascript is here is that in fact I needed to call a method from the webpage that was printed by the java web application, but that was irrelevant cause my doubt was for the use of the " symbol. I thank all for the quick answer.

Comment: by `java` do you mean javascript? if so, retag your question and modify your title.

Comment: Why do you need to change double-quotes (`"`) to single-quotes (`'`)?

Comment: no, i'm calling a javascript from a java class that generates dynamic webpages. it's java but with a call from a java script.

Comment: i need to change the quotes because to print the webpage i'm using the " "+ tags to put html and generate a webpage. And because i'm working in java i cant use the " " in the html, needing to substitute it for ' for working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just escape it with backslash in your Java program when you create the strings.

```
"<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"3\" cellpadding=\"0\" class=\"t1\">"+
"<tr><td>"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and the quick answer, my javascript call now works in the webpage generated by the java code.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you can include a double quote in a String by escaping the `"` character like this: `\"`.

So you're string would look like this:

```
"<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"3\" cellpadding=\"0\" class=\"t1\">"+
    "<tr><td>"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Javascript expert (this question was tagged as Java when it appears it should be tagged as Javascript), but can you not escape double quotes in Javascript as \" ?

Answer (score 2):

try using **\"** inside your quotations.

Comment: exactly what @Tim Bender and @Kal said

Comment: I thank you anyway, when you answered you didn't knew that it was already answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If `\'` is not working then you can try with `\\'`